# AJAX calls should be on the server?

Tags: ajax, node.js, api, express, reactjs

I am building a React/Express/Node app and am trying to make AJAX requests to Instagram. Unfortunately, I keep running into an error when I do so:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But I have set my headers

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

While I have tried making these requests locally, I also have deployed with heroku and also tried to use a https (rather than a http) url. Yet, I still receive the same error.

So for some reason this isn't allowed. I guess this isn't possible (if it is, please let me know). Also Instagram has this option on your app setup:

---

[ ] Disable implicit OAuth

Disable the Client-Side (Implicit) OAuth flow for web apps. If you check this option, Instagram will better protect your application by only allowing authorization requests that use the Server-Side (Explicit) OAuth flow. The Server-Side flow is considered more secure. See the Authentication documentation for details.

---

So then, should I have the user click a button, send the request to my back end, make the ajax request on my back end and when I receive a response, then give it back to the front end? This seems convoluted, but the message above makes it sound like this is more secure. But it requires way more network requests. What is best?

Comment: Last paragraph describes a proxy which is needed if API doesn't support CORS or jsonp. Setting headers yourself is useless ... the remote server needs to set them

Comment: Last paragraph of what?

Comment: Last paragraph of your question

Comment: Then maybe this isn't what I should do. Since I am using the Instagram api and I should be able to make an AJAX request with an access token.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will ignore typical CORS related headers when you are requesting anything from `localhost`. Set up a local development domain (via your `/etc/hosts` on *nix for example) and then try communicating with either your expressjs or Instagram's API again and it should work.

Proxying via your own application as you have outlined in your question is typically only useful when a third party API does not set proper CORS related headers on their API. The reason for this is server API calls (via `curl` for example) do not implement CORS and hence do not do preflight request (such as OPTIONS http calls). Browsers on the other hand do, but they don't work properly when you are accessing things from the `localhost` domain.